# Search SQL table using excel to return only matching values

Tags: sql, excel

I have a large table in my SQL database with a few million rows so I can't just load it into excel. I'd like to setup a data connection in Excel to the database which I can do now, but I want to be able to open the excel sheet, type my search parameter in a cell and then have the matching rows returned from the database table into the excel sheet.
Does anyone know if that's possible? I can't find a way to do it without manually adjusting the search term in the connection properties because I don't know how to pass along what I typed in the cell to be the search term.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server?)
'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, microsoft has a great guide for it here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-parameter-query-in-microsoft-query-c67d9af7-c8a0-4bf7-937c-087cb25f7ad3